# Maven version error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

I've installed maven and configured it correctly. I downloaded the bin file. I set my JAVA_HOME and MAVEN_HOME and put them in my path. But when I put `mvn -version` in the command window I get this error:

```
Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher
```

I've searched and searched. I tried putting M3_HOME, M2_HOME, M2E_HOME, nothing works!

Comment: Please add operating system and exact command you are executing.

Comment: I assume you have downloaded the `..-bin.zip` for windows or `..-bin.tar.gz` for linux. Remove any environment variable like `M2_HOME`, `MAVEN_HOME` etc. from your environment. Only add the location of the bin directory to your PATH variable and of course keep JAVA_HOME...

Comment: Thanks!! I tried this and it didn't work. I went directly to the bin folder in the terminal and tried mvn -version and it still didn't work. It seems that my computer is not allowing the launcher in the file to execute or something.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10. When I go into the terminal and type mvn -version I get the error.